# How to access short_description of a property in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

If I have a Django model with a property defined as

```
def __task_state(self):
    if self.task_id is None:
        return None
    else:
        return # Calculate state somehow

__task_state.short_description = _("Task State")

# Task state
task_state = property(__task_state)
```

Now how do I access short_description for the property?

I am trying to iterate over all properties and field for the model so I can get verbose_name equivalent to use in detailed view and for list view column header.

I can't use `__task_state.short_description` directly and I can't figure out how to get this info using `task_state`
doc() function says not defined, `short_description` is obviously not going to be an attribute of property.
Can't seem to find anything on it anywhere.
Everywhere all it says is use short_description for property text but no one mentions how to access it.

This is how I am trying to find all properties for my model in case anyone feel its relevant

```
    # Get property (name, value) set for the object
    def get_properties(self):
        # Get all properties
        property_names = [
            name
            for name in dir(Job)
            if isinstance(getattr(Job, name), property)
        ]

        # Return list
        result = []

        # Let's prune out pk from the result as we don't want it
        for name in property_names:
            if name == "pk":
                continue

            # TODO: Get short_description for the property somehow
            # Have property name str for the first value, ***want*** detailed name for the second one and have property value for the third one here
            result.append((name, **name**, getattr(self, name)))

        return result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instances of `property` have their getter method stored as `fget`, also you can store their documentation by passing a keyword argument `doc` (to the `property` decorator) or writing it on the getter method. Instead of accessing its documentation by the instance try using the class:

```
def get_properties(self):
        # Get all properties
        property_names = [
            name
            for name in dir(Job)
            if isinstance(getattr(Job, name), property)
        ]

        # Return list
        result = []

        # Let's prune out pk from the result as we don't want it
        for name in property_names:
            if name == "pk":
                continue
            short_description = getattr(Job, name).fget.short_description
            # short_description = getattr(Job, name).__doc__
            result.append((name, short_description, getattr(self, name)))

        return result
```

Comment: Thank you so much! ```getattr(Job, name).fget.short_description``` works perfectly, however getattr(Job, name).__doc__ still gives back 'None' for the code I have in the post.
When I change my property description to 
```task_state = property(__task_state, doc=__task_state.short_description)```
doc works as you suggested!
Is this how you suggested it should be written?

Comment: @LLawliet If you add a docstring (a triple quoted string at start of the method) to the `__task_state` (fget / getter) method it would automatically be used as the docstring for the propery